# Identify and Block Traffic from Amazon AWS servers

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, exchange-2013

We run an in-house Exchange server and noticed a lot of traffic lately coming from Amazon IP's.  The weird thing is the traffic isn't SMTP; rather it seems to be hitting port 443 (which is the OWA / ECP website of the Client Access Server).

We're confused as to the purpose of this traffic.  One thought that occurred to us is perhaps one of the users signed up for a third-party service, running on AWS infrastructure, that periodically (excessively) logs into OWA to do synchronization.  But we're not clear whether sessions are even logging in as a user, or just scraping the sign-in landing page.

We tried blocking the observed addresses to see if something "breaks", but the traffic just comes back again a short time later from a different set of Amazon IP's.

I opened a friendly ticket with abuse@amazon.com but so far they haven't turned up anything useful.

1. How can I identify what this traffic is trying to do?
2. How can I block all traffic to my server originating from IP's belonging to Amazon AWS?

Comment: I did try [ExMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508855(v=exchg.65).aspx) but it didn't turn up anything too unexpected and seems more focused on the internal Exchange side of things than the IIS perimeter.

Answer (score 0):

#### Blocking the traffic

I created a temporary [sledgehammer](https://github.com/rkagerer/BlockAmazon) to take care of #2.

> The authoritative list of all AWS IP ranges is published by Amazon at
>   https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json. The list can be
>   updated several times a week, and is described in more detail in [this
>   blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-ip-ranges-json/).
>
> The program downloads and parses the list, and creates (or updates) a
>   block rule in Windows Firewall.

Amidst increasing numbers of somewhat identity-obscured services running off of AWS infrastructure, maybe this will help others who run into similar issues.

#### Investigating the traffic

For #1, these LogParser [Lizard](https://lizard-labs.com/log_parser_lizard.aspx) queries were helpful:

```
SELECT * FROM #IISW3C#
WHERE c-ip in ('35.153.205.73'; '52.45.133.113'; /* additional IP's here */)
```

Group by month, url and user:

```
SELECT TO_STRING(date, 'yyyy-MMM') AS Month, cs-uri-stem, cs-username, COUNT(*) AS Hits
FROM #IISW3C#
WHERE c-ip in ('35.153.205.73'; '52.45.133.113'; /* additional IP's here */)
GROUP BY Month, cs-uri-stem, cs-username
ORDER BY Month, cs-uri-stem, cs-username
```

#### Results

[image]

No surprise, it was hits to `/EWS/Exchange.asmx` and `/EWS/Services.wsdl`.  The user agent was generally either blank, `Python-urllib/2.7`, `python-requests/2.8.1` or `python-requests/2.9.0`.  Response codes were `401.0` (unauthorized), `401.1` (invalid credentials) and `200.0` (ok).  There were lots of each.

All the `200` ones were using credentials of a single user on our domain.  I'm guessing they signed up for a service like Amazon WorkMail API (push notifications for email delivery / calendar updates), Amazon Comprehend (sentiment analysis of incoming email), Alexa for Business (ask Alexa about scheduled events, add new ones by voice), or a third-party totally unrelated to the Amazon brand who happens to run an EWS client from Amazon infrastructure.

We're following up with the user.  If anyone has a better guess as to what product it might be I'd be interested in hearing it.  This thing generated about 25k hits in the first 10 days of March and some of them took a long time to complete (probably returned a lot of data).  I know that's small potatoes by Amazon-standards, but it was enough for us to take notice.

Comment: Sledgehammer... or possibly a footgun.  There should have been something in your logs that would give you an idea of the nature of this traffic... The content of the HTTP `User-Agent` string often offers an explanation, even if sometimes a ridiculous one... or the presence of `X-Forwarded-For` or `Via` in the requests might have been informative, for example, less for their specific content than for what they might imply.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for the suggestion. Using LogParser I was able to track it down to /EWS/Exchange.asmx and /EWS/Services.wsdl requests under the credentials of one of our users.  Guessing they signed up for something like Alexa for Business, Amazon Comprehend, something using Amazon WorkMail API, or a third-party using EWS from Amazon infrastructure. Any way to dig deeper and capture the POST request data?  BTW user agent is just `python-requests/2.9.0`

Comment: Workmail Calendar Sync seems like a good candidate.  *"Exchange Web Services (EWS) URL—The URL to which Amazon WorkMail sends HTTPS requests to access calendar free/busy information of users on Microsoft Exchange. The EWS URL usually looks like the following: `.../EWS/Exchange.asmx`."*  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/adminguide/enable_interop_wm.html